# How can I create a "volleyball sphere" for sculpting?

Tags: objects

When sculpting, I have seen many people use a sphere with a special topology as a starting point in blender. While a regular `UV sphere` has smaller faces near the two poles, this type of sphere had equal-size faces all around.

Unfortunately, I don't know it's name, so I can't really search how to add it. I'd expect it to be easy to add given how many people use it, but I haven't had any luck finding it in Blender. It's shape reminds me of the seams of a classic volleyball, hence the title:

[image: Volleyball Seams]

Comment: I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but if you enable the *Extra Objects* add-on (*Edit > Preferences > Add-ons*) you can use *Add > Mesh > Round Cube* to create something similar.

Comment: @RobertGützkow ah, that plugin also tells me the name! "quadrilateralized spherical cube", or "quad sphere" for short. I'd pick this as an answer if I could, since the add-on gives a better result than the other answer.

Comment: Give me a moment and I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A *quad sphere* also known as *quadrilateralized spherical cube* can be created with the *Extra Objects* add-on.

1. Open the add-on preferences (*Edit > Preferences > Add-ons*)
2. Search for *Extra Objects* and enable the *Add Mesh: Extra Objects* add-on by ticking the checkbox.
   [image: Add-ons]
3. Add a *quad sphere* through *Add > Mesh > Round Cube*. The default preset that the operator is a *quad sphere*. You can adjust the parameters in the *Adjust Last Operation* panel in the lower left corner. The *arc* property controls the number of arc curve divisions.
   [image: Add Object]
   [image: Properties]

Answer (score 7):

You can make such object as well.

1. Start with a default cube
2. Add a *Subdivision Modifier*
3. Add *Cast Modifier*, factor set to 1, to make it into a sphere

[image]

Comment: This is clever! However it doesn't produce the equal-area property that the add-on that was also mentioned does. So I'll prefer that when it's available.

Comment: Sure, the addon is way more practical :). This was just to show how it works.

Comment: Instead of the Cast Modifier, you can also go into Edit Mode, select everything, then hit Shift-Alt-S and drag your mouse to the right.

Answer (score 3):

You can also bevel the default cube.
Then you can easily choose the number of sides.

1. Bevel the default cube (*Bevel modifier*)
2. Merge double vertices (*Weld modifier*)
3. Done.

[image]